# External JARS in the classpath issue with Java(ANT and Eclipse)

Tags: java, ant

I am working on a Java+ANT+Netty project. The ANT build is failing even though I have added the required external jars in the classpath,

```
    <classpath>
          <pathelement path="/home/pc19/Downloads/mail/netty-all-4.1.10.Final.jar"/>
    </classpath>

    <classpath>
         <pathelement path="/home/pc19/Downloads/mail/netty-all-4.1.10.Final-sources.jar"/>
    </classpath>
```

On building, I am getting netty related error, basically complaing about JARS missing.

Error

```
[javac]   symbol:   class DatagramPacket
[javac]   location: class UdpServerHandler
[javac] /home/pc19/Documents/workspace/GenericDCS/src/org/opengts/servers/dcs_gen/UdpServerHandler.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
```

For the same project, when I import the two jars in eclipse with `Add External Jars`. The errors are resolved.

Does anybody how to resolve this issue.

Comment: One of those looks like a source code jar and shouldn't be in the classpath. afaik, you should only have *one* `classpath` element too

Comment: Share the code where that symbol is referenced including imports and the Ant build script.

Comment: @g00se what do you propose as workaround? regarding your comment related to source_code jar?

Comment: I don't understand. Having a source code jar in the classpath makes no sense at all. You need to remove it

Comment: @g00se so where does it go then? The source  code jar. It is an external jar right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even interested in it. It shouldn't be part of an Ant project at all normally. Forget about it. The only time you might be interested in it is if you wanted to debug into it

Comment: @g00se I don't understand. The project clearly requires it as an dependency. Also, I added it as an external dependency in eclipse, and the problems got resolved. So, create the external dependency needs to be added? What am I doing doing here, I don't understand?

Comment: Let me ask you: what is a " dependency"?

Comment: @g00se the project clearly uses some java files used in the external jar. Proof is eclipe adding external jar, resolving the import/class errors. So, that counts as a depedency, right?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Also, that version of Netty is pretty old